# removing special character from pandas.Series in python?

Tags: python, flask

i'm working on project called financial and in that i got output but i want to remove '-' symbol from my dataframe i tried more please can anyone help me thanks in advance.

my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.json import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/sampleCalc", methods=['post'])
def samplecalc():
    interestrate = float(request.json['interest'])
    years = int(request.json['duration'])/12
    paymentsyear = 12
    principal = int(request.json['principal'])
    currentdate = date.today()
    start_date = (date(currentdate.year, currentdate.month, currentdate.day))
    rng = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=years * paymentsyear, freq='MS')
    rng.name = "paymentDate"
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=rng, columns=['payment', 'roundpayment', 'principal', 'roundprincipal', 'interest', 'roundinterest', 'balance'],
                      dtype='float')
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.index += 1
    df.index.name = "Period"
    df["payment"] = np.pmt(interestrate / paymentsyear, years * paymentsyear, principal)
    df['roundpayment'] = round(df['payment'])
    df["principal"] = np.ppmt(interestrate / paymentsyear, df.index, years * paymentsyear, principal)
    df['roundprincipal'] = round(df['principal'])
    df["interest"] = np.ipmt(interestrate / paymentsyear, df.index, years * paymentsyear, principal)
    df['roundinterest'] = round(df['interest'])
    df = df.round(2)
    df["balance"] = 0
    df.loc[1, "balance"] = principal + df.loc[1, "principal"]
    for i in range(2, len(df) + 1):
        prev_balance = df.ix[i - 1, 'balance']
        principal = df.ix[i, 'principal']

        if prev_balance == 0:
            df.ix[i, ['payment', 'roundpayment', 'principal', 'roundprincipal', 'interest', 'roundinterest', 'balance']] = 0
            continue
        if abs(principal) <= prev_balance:
            df.ix[i, 'balance'] = principal + prev_balance

        else:

            if prev_balance <= abs(principal):
                principal = -prev_balance
                # addl_principal = 0
            else:
                print('else')
            df.ix[i, 'balance'] = 0
            df.ix[i, 'principal'] = principal
            df.ix[i, "payment"] = principal + df.ix[i, "interest"]
    df = df.round(2)
    d = [{k: df.values[i][v] for v, k in enumerate(df.columns)} for i in range(len(df))]
    return jsonify({"data": d})



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my code from this will get the emi calculation based on principal amount and interest and duration below i mentioned my input by using that input will get the output like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "balance": 100414.94,
            "interest": -1666.67,
            "payment": -101251.73,
            "paymentDate": "Sat, 01 Jun 2019 00:00:00 GMT",
            "principal": -99585.06,
            "roundinterest": -1667,
            "roundpayment": -101252,
            "roundprincipal": -99585
        },
        {
            "balance": 0,
            "interest": -836.79,
            "payment": -101251.73,
            "paymentDate": "Mon, 01 Jul 2019 00:00:00 GMT",
            "principal": -100414.94,
            "roundinterest": -837,
            "roundpayment": -101252,
            "roundprincipal": -100415
        }
    ]
}
```

my input is

```
{
    "principal":200000,
    "interest":0.10,
    "duration":2
}
```

i want to remove - symbol from the output.

Comment: You just want to keep absolute value of numbers? `abs(round(df['principal']))` would do that

Comment: exactly @Will  in above output payment and interest,principal,etc, amount is appear with minus symbol so i want to make all output as positive number but the value should not change but the symbol should change as positive.

Comment: @Will if i use abs(round(df['principal'])) but my values will be changing i don't want to change my current value and it should not change.

Comment: "i want to remove - symbol from the output." implies changing a number. OR do you mean you don't want to change it in the dataframe, only in the JSON output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the Dataframe in tact but just affect the JSON output, then get the absolute value of the number when you create the dict that you jsonify.

```
# d = [{k: df.values[i][v] for v, k in enumerate(df.columns)} for i in range(len(df))]
d = df.to_dict("records")

keys_to_change = ["principal", "interest"]   # add whatever keys you want here

for record in d:
    for key in keys_to_change:
        record[key] = abs(record[key])

json_data = jsonify({"data": d})
```

---

To do this for dynamically all numeric values:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
#... 
for record in d:
    for key in record.keys():
        if pd.api.types.is_number(record[key]:
            record[key] = abs(record[key])
```